# Often CSV files use a tab delimiter, how can the Univocity Parsers .csv parser be configured to allow a tab delimiter?

Tags: parsing, csv

Often CSV files use a tab delimiter, how can Univocity Parsers be configured so that the following can use a tab delimiter?:

```
CsvParserSettings parserSettings = new CsvParserSettings();
```

When parsing .csv files delimited by tabs is required, although Univocity Parsers has a TSVreader, having more than one settings instance creates coding obstacles.

The code and stack trace are below.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
import com.univocity.parsers.csv.CsvParserSettings;
import com.univocity.parsers.common.processor.*;
import com.univocity.parsers.csv.*;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.Reader;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.lang.IllegalStateException;
import java.lang.String;
import java.util.List;


public class UnivocityParsers {

public Reader getReader(String relativePath) {
    try {
        return new InputStreamReader(this.getClass().getResourceAsStream(relativePath), "Windows-1252");
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        throw new IllegalStateException("Unable to read input", e);
    }
}


public void columnSelection() {
    RowListProcessor rowProcessor = new RowListProcessor();
    CsvParserSettings parserSettings = new CsvParserSettings();

    parserSettings.setRowProcessor(rowProcessor);
    parserSettings.setHeaderExtractionEnabled(true);
    parserSettings.setLineSeparatorDetectionEnabled(true);
    parserSettings.setSkipEmptyLines(true);
    parserSettings.getFormat().setDelimiter('\t');

    // Here we select only the columns "Price", "Year" and "Make".
    // The parser just skips the other fields
    parserSettings.selectFields("AUTHOR", "ISBN");

    CsvParser parser = new CsvParser(parserSettings);
    parser.parse(getReader("list4.csv"));

    List<String[]> rows = rowProcessor.getRows();

    String[] strings = rows.get(0);

    System.out.print(strings[0]);

}


public static void main(String arg[]) {

    UnivocityParsers univocityParsers = new UnivocityParsers();

    univocityParsers.columnSelection();


}


}
```

Stack trace:

```
    Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at java.io.Reader.<init>(Reader.java:78)
at java.io.InputStreamReader.<init>(InputStreamReader.java:97)
at parse.Controller.getReader(Controller.java:34)
at parse.Controller.columnSelection(Controller.java:107)
... 56 more
```

Here is the file being parsed:

```
"REVIEW_DATE"   "AUTHOR"    "ISBN"  "DISCOUNTED_PRICE"
"1985/01/21"    "Douglas Adams" 345391802   5.95
"1990/01/12"    "Douglas Hofstadter"    465026567   9.95
"1998/07/15"    "Timothy ""The Parser"" Campbell"   968411304   18.99
"1999/12/03"    "Richard Friedman"  60630353    5.95
"2001/09/19"    "Karen Armstrong"   345384563   9.95
"2002/06/23"    "David Jones"   198504691   9.95
"2002/06/23"    "Julian Jaynes" 618057072   12.5
"2003/09/30"    "Scott Adams"   740721909   4.95
"2004/10/04"    "Benjamin Radcliff" 804818088   4.95
"2004/10/04"    "Randel Helms"  879755725   4.5
```

Comment: Are you able to set the delimiter to be the raw hex value 0x09?

Comment: When trying to set the delimiter to tab using: `parserSettings.getFormat().setDelimiter((char) 0x09);` an error occurs: `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem comes from the `getReader` method. It is not finding the file in your classpath.

This line is producing a `null`:

```
this.getClass().getResourceAsStream(relativePath)
```

Maybe you should use this (note the leading slash on the file name):

```
parser.parse(getReader("/list4.csv"));
```

Also note that the TSV parser is a different implementation. TSV is not just CSV with tab delimiters (it's all good if in your case it works). Just keep in mind trying to read a TSV using a CSV parser is a bad idea as characters such as '\n' or '\t' may be escaped as actual sequences of '\' and 'n'. When a CSV parser reads this you will get the 2 characters ('\' + 'n') instead of the new line character ('\n')